# React Native: Dynamically print Text in multiple color

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render a Text content on App by using React Native. The Text content is loaded from the server. Beside the content itself, the network response also tells me those words indexes which should be rendered in a different color.

For example:

```
// from the response JSON, I can tell:

contentString='How can we dynamic render text in multiple colors?'

index=[1, 3, 5]
```

I need to render the `contentString` in black on the App and render `can`(index 1), `dynamic`(index 3) and `text(index 5)` in yellow.

I did some researches on that and I noticed "Nested Text" would be a solution. Like:

```
<Text style={{color: 'black'}}>
  how
  <Text style={{color: 'yellow'}}>
    can
  </Text>
  we
  <Text style={{color: 'yellow'}}>
    dynamic
  </Text>

.......

</Text>
```

The index array differs from each request. I tried my best to write a function to support this DYNAMICALLY multi-color rendering, but with no luck. I'm still learning the algorithm and this function seems too challenging..

Can anyone throw some light on this? Much appreciates!

Comment: But in your example mark-up, you seem to be rendering 1,3,5 words in black, but your expectation was to render 1,3,5 in yellow. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sateesh In my example, 1,3,5 will be rendered in yellow. You can see the 'can' is a child prop of `<Text style={{color: 'yellow'}}>`. Not sure how can I make it dynamically based on the index array.

Comment: my bad. Please check my answer.

Comment: @sateesh Thanks for your supports and idea. Your solution is super! I learned a lot from it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this..

```
 <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>
     {contentString.split(" ").map((x, ind) => 
           <Text style={{color: index.includes(ind)?'black':'yellow'}}>
            {x+ " "}
           </Text>)
      }
 </Text>
```

[Live Demo Here](https://snack.expo.io/@sat333sh/conditional-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

- In Render create array of colors
- random function for get random number every time
- you pass the random number in backColor array. index of the colors array

```
render() {

var backColor = ["#c36a2d", "#afa939", "#60204b", "#ca3e47", "#f7b71d", "#f36886", "#614ad3", "#0c99c1", "#4e3440", "#010059"];
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

    return (
       <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>
         {contentString.split(" ").map((x, ind) => 
             <Text style={{color: backColor[rand]}}>
              {x+ " "}
             </Text>)
          }
      </Text>
   )
}
```

Comment: That's nice. I believe the trick is to have the `contentString.split(" ").map((x, ind)`.